# Display a particular row value at the end Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have some rows in a table and i wanted to display a particular row at the end. Can i do that in the query ?I wanted some thing like this.

[image]

I wanted to display the comments at the end of the table.

Comment: apply order by feedback ASC to get the comments at the last

Comment: How do you want to order the rest of the values in the column? Alphabetical by the feedback component name? Sounds like you want to order by a case statement.

Comment: @Bridge rest should be same i just wanted the commets to be at last

Comment: @HappyCoding but then the order of others will also change i wanted them to be same :|

Comment: @Jason you can set the position of each component by making a new column, then apply order by as per your need.

Comment: @Jason How is the order defined in your current query? Are the component names fixed?

Comment: @Bridge yeah component names are fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with a psydo column

```
SELECT `feedback component`, 
        feedback, 
        `feedback component` = 'Comments' AS Filter
FROM    table 
ORDER BY Filter
```

Maybe you have to use a sub select if `ORDER BY Filter` don't work direct

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT feedback_component, feedback
FROM table 
WHERE feedback > 0

UNION ALL

SELECT feedback_component, feedback
FROM table
WHERE concat('',feedback * 1) != feedback;
```

hope it will meet your requirement

Comment: it is giving the order of the but not displaying the comments row :|

Answer (score 0):

As your component names are fixed, and there doesn't seem to be any other way to logically order the rows (not in alphabetical order, no other column provided which defines the order) I don't see any other way to do this than a case statement which defines the order:

```
SELECT `Feedback Component`,
       `Feedback`
FROM   YourTable /* Fill in these bits with your names */
ORDER  BY CASE `Feedback Component`
            WHEN 'Clarity of session objectives' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Questions answered clearly and completely' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Trainers knowledge level' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Usefulness of session to your work' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Overall session rating' THEN 5
            WHEN 'Comments' THEN 6
          END
```